# Django: ModelForm confusion

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to display a bound ModelForm in my template.

Here the the code from the view:

```
assessment = Assessment.objects.get(slug=slug)
form = AssessmentForm(assessment)
```

But when I then pull up the template, it is empty except for the submit button.

When I try to debug with PDB, I get:

```
(Pdb) form.data
<Assessment: Alaska - Coastal Forests>
(Pdb) form.as_p
<bound method AssessmentForm.as_p of <cst.assessapp.models.AssessmentForm object at 0x224b190>>
(Pdb) form.as_p()
*** AttributeError: 'Assessment' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So, obviously, I am doing something wrong. Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the `Assessment` instance to the form class using the `instance` keyword argument.

```
form = AssessmentForm(instance = assessment)
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for more details.